# Raspberry Pi 2 - Help with Wifi Access Point

Tags: wifi, pi-2

I was looking for a project for my RPI2 and found a [webpage](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point) that shows you how to transform your Pi into a wireless access point. Sounds fun, right?

Well, I've done all of the steps and believed I was ready to rock with this project. However, the problem I'm getting is that the guide was made for people with a specific WiFi Dongle (the one that adafruit makes) and that's not the one I'm using.

Naturally, since I'm using an RT5730 from Ralink, I thought I just needed to edit the "driver" setting in `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` with my driver's chipset, `RT5730`. It didn't work, though, and I've been trying for about half an hour to get some name that actually works. So, all I need to know is what to write inside of the "driver" section. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the contents of the "hostapd.conf" file:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=RPi
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=myownkey
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
driver=nl80211
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nl80211` in your driver settings.

```
driver=nl80211
```

Comment: Nope, still gives me the error:`Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf Line 12: invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211' 1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'`

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch Can you edit the question and add the entire contents of `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`?

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch I don't see anything wrong with it. What's your OS? (Raspbian? Arch? Something else?)

Comment: The OS I'm running is Raspbian off of the NOOBS installer. With Raspberry Pi 2 B. The WiFi dongle I'm using is the one off of http://canakit.net (where I bought my kit from). I've tried to get my other WiFi dongles working, but to no avail.

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch Have you tried removing the line?

Comment: Just tried that. Now I get this error: `Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
drv->ifindex=3
l2_sock_recv==l2_sock_xmit=0x0x1721638
ioctl[SIOCSIWMODE]: Invalid argument
Could not set interface to mode(3)!
Could not set interface to master mode!
rtl871xdrv driver initialization failed.
`

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch Have you tried `sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink`?

Comment: Already installed.

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch I've come to the conclusion that you may need to recompile `hostapd` with the missing drivers. As scary as it may sound, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: And how would I do that? I'm a complete Linux noob so sorry if these questions are stupid.

Comment: @AlexandreVoloch Try this: http://www.jenssegers.be/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi

Comment: Now whenever I type `pi@raspberrypi:~/RTL8188-hostapd-2.0/hostapd $ sudo service hostapd restart`, I get this error:
`Warning: Unit file of hostapd.service changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.`

Comment: I thought about restarting the machine, so I did `shutdown -r now` and now whenever I type `sudo service hostapd restart`, I get no response.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom `hostapd` - see [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=19120&start=250)

Details: Hostapd contains just "too standard" drivers inside it's distribution, so there are additional "add-ons" to the source tree, that leaded to some forks. Theese forks are working as usual in common cases, and in their specific cases they're working differently. For your case you need to try [this realtek-specific fork](https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31033)

Comment: @Jacobm001 OK, I'll fix it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was that I had to use different hostapd binary:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Both builtin chip and DWA-125 worked for me.